# Rspec testing view test fails but HTML is OK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

With Rspec, I'm testing the presence of the logo in the navnar:

```
#spec/views/_header_spec.html.erb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "layouts/_header.html.erb" do
  subject{rendered}


  it "should have the clickable logo" do
    render
    should have_selector("img")
    should have_link("/")
  end
end
```

This is my generated HTML:

```
<a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
  <img alt="Logo" src="/assets/logo.png">
</a>
```

The page is OK, but the test fails:

```
$rspec spec/views/_header_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) layouts/_header.html.erb should have the clickable logo
     Failure/Error: should have_link("/")
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find link "/" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/views/_header_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.13914 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/views/_header_spec.rb:7 # layouts/_header.html.erb should have the clickable logo

Randomized with seed 37707
```

The test fails, but the HTML behaviour page is correct, so I think my test is not working properly. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
should have_link("/")
```

With

```
should have_link("Logo", href: "/")
```

`have_link` takes the `display text` of the link or `alt` attribute value of an image, and using the `href` option you can specify the corresponding path.